# get last 3 month on year in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to get last 3 months name from current month. For example current month is December. So, I want get like this October, November and December.

This is my query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)) AS MonthName, ItemId
FROM dbo.Issue AS Issue
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)), ItemId
HAVING (ItemId = 427)
```

This returns:
[image]

But, my need is:

[image]

**N.B. When December month close and January month open then October auto excluded as like (November, December and January)**

**this link is my Database only 2 table (size-243 KB with Zip) on the google drive** **`https://goo.gl/S4m0R5`**

Answer (score 0):

Add a date diff in a where clause to filter to the last 3 months, and then order by the month number at the end:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, [IssueDate])) AS MonthName, ItemId
FROM  [dbo].[Issue] AS Issue
WHERE datediff(m, [IssueDate], getdate()) between 0 and 2
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, [IssueDate])), ItemId, MONTH(IssueDate)
HAVING (ItemId= 427)
order by MONTH(IssueDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD function:

```
WHERE IssueDate >= dateadd( month, -2, dateadd( day, -datepart( day, getdate() ) + 1, cast( getdate() as date ) ) )
```

That will give you IssueDate >= '2015-10-01' given today.

That will also work with index you have on IssueDate, if you start doing something like DATEADD / DATEDIFF etc. on IssueDate then the index can only be scanned end-to-end because it needs to processs all rows in the table so renders the index significantly less effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    IssueDate DATETIME,
    ItemId INT
)

INSERT INTO @t (IssueDate, ItemId)
VALUES
    ('20160105', 427),
    ('20151212', 427),
    ('20151213', 427),
    ('20151110', 427),
    ('20151001', 427),
    ('20150905', 427)

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dt)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(3) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, IssueDate), 0) AS dt
    FROM @t
    WHERE ItemId = 427
    ORDER BY dt DESC
) t
```

results -

```
------------------------------
January
December
November
```

Comment: Dear @Devart, your query is ok. But, my need this result - plz c this Result on google deive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_k-gFpZlM3JQTRUY2JmZzdFWWs/view?usp=sharing). plz soon as possible solve this.

Comment: plz check my Database (size-243 KB with Zip) on the google drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_k-gFpZlM3JYkVfT1Z6dmJiUEk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get month names for the last 12 months and then limit it to the last 3 month names in the second part of the query:

```
;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
   SELECT 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT MonthNumber+1 
   FROM months
   WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-MonthNumber,GETDATE())) AS [month]
FROM dbo.Issue AS Issue
CROSS JOIN months m
WHERE m.MonthNumber <3
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-MonthNumber,GETDATE())) , ItemId
HAVING (ItemId = 427)
```